# the resource viewmodellocator could not be resolved

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

Im trying to create a project which uses mvvmlight. In my viewmodellocator I have.

```
namespace WPFService.ViewModel
{
    public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        public ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
        }

        public MainViewModel MainView
        {

            get
            {
                return new MainViewModel(new DummyQuestionRepository());
            }
        }

        public static void Cleanup()
        {
            // TODO Clear the ViewModels
        }
    }
}
```

In my App.xaml I have:

```
<Application x:Class="WPFService.App" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" d1p1:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WPFService.ViewModel" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

WPFService is my namespace

In my MainWindow.xaml I want to bind to the MainViewModel (from MainView) with the following code:

```
 <Window x:Class="WPFService.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="900"
     DataContext="{Binding MainView, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}">
```

However I keep getting the error

> the resource viewmodellocator could not be resolved

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ViewModelLocator` instance in application resources dictionary is stored under the "Locator" key (`x:Key="Locator"`), so you should use that key in your static resource reference. Note that the full syntax is the following:

```
{StaticResource ResourceKey=Locator}
```

and in short

```
{StaticResource Locator}
```